# Contour border-like style in matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to plot some data on a graph, and I would like to stack a tricontour plot over a tricontourf one.

I have managed to draw the following :
[image: Current state of picture]

The contour lines are however difficult to read.

To make it more legible, I would like to change the plain line of the contour plot to something like this (with the hashes toward the low values) :

[image: What I want to achieve]

I have never seen such plot made with matplotlib. 
So here are my questions : is it possible to draw contours like that ? If so, how can I do it ?

Comment: Do you insist on `tricontour(f)`? I *think* it could be done in a hacky way with `contourf`, but not with `tricontourf`.

Comment: My data is not evenly placed on a grid, so I think that tricontour(f) is the appropriate function. It would anyway answer the the question "is it possible" if you have have a solution for contour(f), so I will also accept a solution for contour(f).

Comment: No, sorry, I got a bit confused late at night:) For some reason I didn't realize that you actually need meshed data for `contour` (I honestly can't tell how). Furthermore, it's not even satisfactory for `contourf`. My idea was to use the `hatched` keyword argument that can be used with certain back-ends, but the result is really ugly (since neighbouring contour lines are almost never parallel), something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SuMI4.png) (the colours would be removed, and additional contour lines added with a call to `contour`, but it still doesn't cut it).